# Efficient computation of $A^\top (AA^\top)^{-1} A v$

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-complexity, matrix-decomposition

Given a full row-rank $m\times n$ matrix $A$ with $n > m$ and a vector $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$, what is the most computationally efficient way of computing this?
$$
x = A^\top(AA^\top)^{-1}A v.
$$
I have some options:

#### Naive Computation

- Compute $Av$.
- Compute $AA^\top$
- Solve the system $AA^\top y = Av$ for $y$. (e.g. using `numpy.linalg.solve()`)
- Compute $x = A^\top y$.

#### QR Decomposition

- Compute $Q = qr(A^\top)$ (e.g. using `scipy.linalg.qr(, mode='economic')`)
- Compute $x = QQ^\top v$

#### Cholesky Decomposition

- Compute $L = \text{Cholesky}(AA^\top)$ lower triangular (e.g. `scipy.linalg.cho_factor()`)
- Solve the system $LL^\top y = Av$ for $y$ (e.g. `scipy.linalg.cho_solve()`)
- Compute $y = A^\top y$

#### LU Decomposition

- Compute $JJ^\top$
- Compute $LU = \text{LuDecomposition}(JJ^\top)$ (e.g. `scipy.linalg.lu_factor()`)
- Solve $LU y = Av$ (e.g. `scipy.linalg.lu_solve()`)
- Compute $x = A^\top y$

Are there  other alternatives?

Comment: there's also the SVD method, but I bet the QR one is the best

Comment: @Exodd how would you do it with SVD?

Comment: if $A=UDV^T$ is the SVD of A, then $x = V D^T(DD^T)^{-1}D V^T v$ but the diagonal at the center is a diagonal $0-1$ matrix easy to compute. Thinking about it, that's totally equivalent to QR

Comment: How is $DV^\top v$ defined, don't they have different dimensions?

Comment: $V$ if $n\times n$ and $D$ is $m\times n$

Comment: In terms of operation count Cholesky decomposition would be efficient, but calculating $AA^T$ might cause round-off issues.

Comment: @greg do you know of any better method?

Comment: @Euler_Salter I agree with Exodd, the QR approach is almost certainly the best here